# Surface tension force between two wet objects

Tags: surface-tension

I have a problem related to surface tension. I hope someone good at physics can help me. The picture attached shows the two cases. I have an elastomeric sphere filled with air (compressible) and a hard polymer cylinder. All surfaces are hydrophilic and wet with water. In both cases, the two objects are pressed against each other by a person. The water meniscus (see the areas filled with black) around the contact interface results in surface tension forces.

In Case1, the cylinder is large, the circular contact area diameter is “a”. In Case2, the cylinder diameter is exactly “a” and it just flushes its flat surface to the sphere. So in both cases, the contact area, and perimeter is the same. In both cases, are the surface tension forces attracting the sphere and the cylinder towards each other, same? Or is my question not complete. [image]

Comment: I think that the tension in the 2Case is greater. In the first case, the cylinder doesn't have the risk to penetrate the ball, but in the second case, it does, so this extra force that avoids the cylinder penetrating must explain the greater tension. I am not completely sure and corrections will be welcomed.

Comment: @MarcBarceló, thanks for your time. Note in both cases, the two surfaces (cylinder and sphere) are hydrophilic. My understanding is that the external forces which press the two objects together are supported (not opposed) by the surface tension forces. In other words, the free surface of the liquid is trying to pull these two objects together. I think you are suggesting otherwise. Open to discussion.

Comment: I would say that if the object was hydrophilic it would sink. If you want we can open a chat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I start to think that my question is not clear. I am new to the platform, I'm not sure how to open a chat, but I'm happy to. 
To make things clear, the sphere and the cylinder are held by a person with his hands. I'm not sure what you mean by "it would sink". Sorry.

Comment: I'll add some more information to the question to make it clearer.